# How to freeze the list of processes in htop?

Tags: unix, terminal, htop

I'd like to stop refreshing the list of processes. My problem is it refreshes itself too often.

How can I do it? I use `htop`.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
For new versions `(>=3.0)` of the `htop` check out this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1633010/106217)

**For versions < `3.0`:**

Most easy way is suspending the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, and unfreezing with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> while `htop` or any other flowing display is running. (Thanks to  [Keith](https://superuser.com/users/76254/keith) for this reminder of easy tip)

Also, you can change refresh interval with putting `-d` key before running the `htop` for example:

```
# htop -d 100
```

The number 100 indicates the delay between updates, in tenths of seconds. You can change the refresh interval as you like. But there is no pausing support for now.

Alternatively, you can use screen capture tools for freezing the moment in graphical interface if you are on any *desktop environment*. In the short hand you can press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd> key at any time. Or you can install and use any kind of *screenshot* or *screen recorder* applications.

Comment: Thank you. What if I set too many seconds and after I want refresh - exists any options how do it?

Comment: I have no idea if there is an option exist. But if you use `top` instead of `htop` you can change refresh interval inside the app by typing `d` key.

Comment: My man says:
 -d --delay=DELAY
              Delay between updates, in tenths of seconds

Comment: I'm surprised nobody said just press CTRL-S

Comment: I hate CTRL-S(uspend) short cut. It freezing terminal when I push that combination accidentally. I hate it so much, that's why I never remember existence of that :D Thank you for your reminder.

Comment: there is a disadvantage of ctrl+s, you cannot select and copy the output.

Comment: All of these kind of suck when you want to freeze thesnapshot and re-order/alter columns, see tree view etc.

Answer (score 33):

In htop version 3.0+, use `Shift Z` inside of htop to pause process list updates. You will still be able to navigate around this way.

If you forget the shortcut, you can find it with `F1` from inside htop, or externally with `man htop`. Just note that they denote `Shift + z` as just one capital letter `Z`.

Comment: It might be noteworthy that this is a new feature in htop 3.x.

Comment: @user1871996: this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated it with that info Daniel. And I added some screenshots.

Answer (score 19):

As [Keith](https://superuser.com/questions/1036978/how-to-freeze-the-list-of-processes-in-htop#comment1933032_1036983) said:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> Freezes the terminal. (You cannot interact with `htop` afterwards.)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> [Unfreezes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12107/how-to-unfreeze-after-accidentally-pressing-ctrl-s-in-a-terminal#12108) the terminal again.

Comment: This works and something I always forget about until I am in VIM and try to use the IDE save shortcuts ;)