# How to pause the output in top

Tags: linux, command-line, top

I distinctly remember there being a key one can press while running `top` that pauses the output, and then you can press the same key again to resume updates.  However I can't seem to remember the key. I've also read through the entire man page and done a good bit of searching on the web and on stack exchange.

Hoping someone knows **what key to press to pause updates in top**.

Side note: I *suppose* there's a small chance I was accomplishing this via tmux and it's not built into top, but I'm fairly certain it was in top.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1036983/1482432  Ctrl-S and Ctrl-D

Comment: or simply hit a key that displays a prompt, set top  to wait for input; e.g. hit `s` or `d` - other alternatives; `h` for help.

Comment: Besides Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q, I also found that the PrntScrn button pauses/resumes terminal output (though not useful for me since I have that mapped to take a screenshot)